# Connecing BizTalk 2010 to an Azure Storage Queue

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2010, azure-appfabric

I have an internal WCF service that needs to connect with an Azure queue.  Does the BizTalk 2010 AppFabric connect tool support storage queues?  According to the following MSDN blog it requires a relay endpoint.  [BizTalk Server 2010 AppFabric Connect for Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalk_server_team_blog/archive/2010/10/21/biztalk-server-appfabric-connect-for-services.aspx).  Is this article still valid?

Can I access Azure storage queues with this approach?  If not, what is the other best approach?  I could do the following but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.

1. Using a reverse proxy expose the internal WCF service as an external WCF service through the firewall
2. Create .NET code that reads the Azure storage queue and calls the WCF service.  If the service call is successful the message is deleted from the queue.